# Loop a list with one sublist at a time

Tags: python

I want to loop in sublists. I achieve it by doing the following code.

```
def batchGenerator(samples, subsetSize):
    i=0
    while (i < (len(samples) - subsetSize + 1)):
        yield samples[i: i + subsetSize]
        i = i + subsetSize
```

Is there a more standard library function to do the same thing?

I want to use it like:

```
for subl in batchGenerator(range(100), 10):
    print (max(subl))
```

Output:

```
9
19
29
39
49
59
69
79
89
99
```

Edit:

I want the trailing elements that are fewer than `subsetSize` to be truncated, and I find @s3cur3 solution the most elegant for this case (compared to the solutions in a similar thread: [What is the most "pythonic" way to iterate over a list in chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks))

I also prefer that the output stays the same type, `list`, `numpy.array`, `torch.Tensor`, etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most "pythonic" way to iterate over a list in chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks)

Comment: Yes its very similar but the solution wouldn't work for me because I want to truncate the last elements that are fewer than `subsetSize`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
def batchGenerator(samples, subsetSize):
    return (samples[i:i+subsetSize] for i  in range(0, len(samples), subsetSize))
```

The `range()` call here lets you iterate up to the length of your list, jumping `subsetSize` at a time (thus giving you an `i` of 0, 10, 20, . . ., 90 in your example).

**Edited to respond to comment**:

If you want to allow the input to be a list-of-lists, you'd need to use generator syntax like this:

```
def batchGenerator(listOfSampleLists, subsetSize):
    for sampleList in listOfSampleLists:
        for i in range(0, len(sampleList), subsetSize):
            yield sampleList[i:i+subsetSize]
```

Comment: Yes this works too. Will it be less memory efficient without `yield`?

Comment: I also prefer my function because it works more generally for `numpy` array, PyTorch `Tensor` without changing the type to a `list`

Comment: Ah, right you are! I've edited the answer to return a generator instead of a list. That should be compatible with the other (non-`list`) types you mentioned, I believe.

Comment: This is very nice! Considering there is no existing library function to already, this solution looks the most elegant. I will mark it as correct answer

Comment: How can we generalise this for multiple inputs? Like batchGenerator((samples_features, samples_label), subsetSize)

Comment: thanks, I modified your code for the functionality I wanted, and suggested an edit.